# rabbitmq erlang ets rpc:call badrpc

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, ets

i have a rabbitmq server running on docker . i want to show the ets tables in rabbitmq.
i use rpc:call to do this,but it does not work.
my rabbit server node name is

```
rabbit@f72eb878386f
```

and i use erl -sname rabbit it tips :

```
Protocol 'inet_tcp': the name rabbit@f72eb878386f seems to be in use by another Erlang node
```

and i use

```
erl -sname node1
```

then.

```
rpc:call('rabbit@f72eb878386f',ets,tab2list,[queue_stats]).
```

error message shows below

```
{badrpc,nodedown}
```

Comment: Do you have the same [cookie](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#get_cookie-0) in both nodes? otherwise the clustering protocol blocks the comunication.

Comment: yes,tanks . i do not set cookie